# How to prove the formal theorem using Ping-Pong $\vdash(( \phi\equiv\psi)\implies\theta[\phi/x])\equiv((\phi\equiv\psi)\implies\theta[\psi/x])$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

> How do I prove this formal theorem using Ping-Pong  $\vdash(( \phi\equiv\psi)\implies\theta[\phi/x])\equiv((\phi\equiv\psi)\implies\theta[\psi/x])$?

I know there is a way using SFL, but, for Ping-Pong, I'm confused. What I tried was doing a Hilbert Style proof (which can be done only for Ping-Pong) and used *Axiom 11* (implication/ or intro to implication), but after I got stuck, I tried to convert the disjunction into conjunction. I got from the Ax.11 by using the golden rule (Ax.10) but does not seem to work. Any help be would appreciated.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a MathJax tutorial :) Furthermore, please include your own attempts, even though they might not have been fruitful at all. So questions do not stand as isolated problems but as actual questions.

Comment: Explain your / notation.

Comment: thank you @mrtaurho for the mathjax tutorial, and I have made some improvements to my question.

Comment: What exactly is "Ping-Pong?"

Comment: @NoahSchweber hopefully this explains it, https://imgur.com/Ag4Jii0